# How to reconcile my odoo account in V8. In case of the cheque bounce of the customer

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

I want to solve this case can anyone help to solve this.

> My case is as on creating **Invoice ->I received a cheque -> and Invoice
>   states we make paid.** considering that we received the payment. as shown in below Image.

[image: Case-1-Invoice-paid]

Now

> **Twist is checked bounce. and a customer gets debited.** and we have not received payment.

[image: Case-1-Invoice-paid-customer-Debited]

How to solve this in odoo V8.

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gone through the roots of it and I found the following solution. Let discuss the Entire case with the solution.

The **Bank Reconciliation Feature** of the odoo we can use here to solve this case.

> To reconcile our account we can go to the following path. **Accounting
>   -> Reconciliation -> Manual Reconciliation -> Create**
>
> There you debit again the amount you want to.
>
> **Note:** On saving this it is showing in the red color it means there is a mismatch. As seen in the below image.

[image: Solution-BRS-1]

> After doing the manual reconciliation we can verify the Journal Entry
>   also. By going to **Accounting Journal Entries -> Journal Entries**

[image: Solution-BRS-2]

> Now on **receiving the payment again from the customer**, create the
>   receipt from this path **Accounting -> Customer -> Sales Receipt**

[image: Solution-BRS-2]

> Then again **reconcile the sales receipt the with precious journal**.
>
> By going to this path  **Accounting -> Reconciliation -> Manual
>   Reconciliation -> Create**

Now,

> Then to verify the result go the path **Accounting -> Journal Entries
>   -> Journal Entries** as shown in below image you will found that **case is solve.**

[image: Solution-BRS-4]